# Why is ram_utilization_factor usage not recommended

Tags: bazel

I wonder why increasing of `--ram_utilization_factor` is not recommended (from the docs):

> This option, which takes an integer argument, specifies what percentage of the system's RAM Bazel should try to use for its subprocesses. This option affects how many processes Bazel will try to run in parallel. The default value is 67. If you run several Bazel builds in parallel, using a lower value for this option may avoid thrashing and thus improve overall throughput. Using a value higher than the default is NOT recommended. Note that Bazel's estimates are very coarse, so the actual RAM usage may be much higher or much lower than specified. Note also that this option does not affect the amount of memory that the Bazel server itself will use.

Since Bazel has no way of knowing how much memory an action/worker uses/will use, the only way of setting this up seems `ram_utilization_factor`.

Answer (score -1):

That comment is very old and I believe was the result of some trial and error when --ram_utilization_factor was first implemented. The comment was added to make sure that developers would have some memory left over for other applications to run on their machines. As far as I can tell, there is no deeper reason for it.